# Minimize the cable cost

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The cost of laying a fibre optic cable underwater is $3$ times that of underground. An island is $4$ km from point S on the shore measured perpendicular to the shore and a broadcast station B is $14$ km along the shore. How should the cable to connect the broadcast station to the island, be laid to keep cost to a minimum?

I am unable to understand the second line. Can anyone make it clear to me, may be with a proper rough image diagram?

I am unable to get the function, which I have to minimize.

Thank you!

Comment: S is in bold so I guess that means a vector. If I is the Island then ISB is a right angled triangle.

Comment: @Paul No. There is no vector. Just point. I've removed the boldness.

Comment: A ship has two masts and is 100 feet long and 20 feet broad. How old is the captain (or this joke, whatever is easier to determine). This an ill posed question.

Comment: Still a right angled triangle

Comment: @Paul Still I am not getting! Can you explain a little bit which function I have to minimize?

Comment: To @Topo: Perhaps you may check [this video](https://youtu.be/34c25jECZTo?si=nV_zQRHLUFx3YpHz) for some idea(s)...

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer (still under the review). As it is, it is a little ambiguous. I think the solution is called minimising the action in physics. The classic example is the path of a light ray refracted as it passes from air to water.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Check out this link https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-asia-china-42857864 "If a ship had 26 sheep and 10 goats onboard, how old is the ship's captain?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Ross' diagram with S at the origin, we lay a cable from B to new point C somewhere between B and S and then continue laying the cable in a straight line from C to the island.

The distance from B to the island using Pythagoras is $\sqrt{(14-y)^2+4^2}$ where y is the distance from B to C.

The total distance as represented by the length of cable to connect B to C to the island is $y + \sqrt{(14-y)^2+4^2}$.

In terms of cost we can say the total "cost distance" (x) is  $x = y + 3 \sqrt{(14-y)^2+4^2}$ where the second term has been multiplied by 3 because that section casts 3 times as much to lay. This "cost distance" is what we are trying to minimise.

To find the minimum, find the derivative of the above equation which is: $\frac {\delta x}{\delta y} = 1 - \frac{3(14-y)}{ \sqrt{(14-y)^2+16}}$

Set $\frac {\delta x}{\delta y}$ equal to zero and solve for y. This is the point on the shore where the cable stops following the shore and heads directly towards the island.

Edit: (Fixed typo in simplification pointed out by Ham Lemon)

The above equation simplifies to $y^2 -28y +194 = 0$ which is a standard quadratic equation.

Comment: There seems to be problem in your final equation because 1) Your final equation has no real roots which for this case should not be possible and 2) After simplification of the $\frac {\delta x}{\delta y}$ equation , I am getting $y^2 - 28y + 194 = 0$ which does have real roots and checking on desmos/wolfram, they match up with the minimum value given for the equation of X you derived.

Comment: Yes. You are right, Thanks.  Fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

It is badly written, but I am sure this is what they mean.  A is the island and B is the broadcast station.  The mainland is the region below the $x$ axis.  The unit is km.  You can lay the cable along the shore for some distance then make an angle to the island.  You are to select the distance to run along the shore to minimize the total cost.

[image]

Comment: Which point is $S$ ? Origin?

Comment: @Topo:  yes, S is the origin but it is not used except to locate the other two points.

Comment: I suggest you edit the question rather than posting an answer without a solution to the OP's problem

Comment: @HamLemon:  The question originally did not understand the locations.  It was later edited to also not know what to do once OP understood that.  I think a complete answer violates our policy on questions with no context.

Comment: Oh, I get it now thanks for explaining it to me